# Calculate/sum area (in hectars) of each pixel value within polygons of a shapefile using GEE Python API

Tags: polygon, intersection, area, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm using the Land Use/Land Cover dataset of Brazil produced by MapBiomas, specifically the age of secondary vegetation available at `projects/mapbiomas-workspace/public/collection6/mapbiomas_collection60_secondary_vegetation_age_v1`.

Now, I need to calculate the area (in hectars) of each vegetation age (columns) by municipality (lines), resulting in a table like this (dummy values), which I can save as CSV:

| Municipality | age1 | age2 | age3 | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 15.2 | 16.0 | 18.5 | … |
| Name2 | 2.2 | 5.7 | 7.4 | … |
| Name3 | 5.4 | 3.4 | 6.1 | … |
| ... | … | … | … | … |

This is what I have done so far:

```py
import ee
ee.Initialize()

# importing the dataset
sec_veget_age = ee.Image('projects/mapbiomas-workspace/public/collection6/mapbiomas_collection60_secondary_vegetation_age_v1')

# selecting only vegetation age layer
sec_veget_age = sec_veget_age.select('secondary_vegetation_age_2018')

# the dataset is coded as age/landcover. I only want landcover forest, coded as 03, so I remap the values to show the ages as pixel values
sec_veget_age = sec_veget_age.select('secondary_vegetation_age_2018').remap(
    [103,203,303,403,503,603,703,803,903,1003,1103,1203,1303,1403,1503,1603,1703,1803,1903,2003,2103,2203,2303,2403,2503,2603,2703,2803,2903,3003,3103,3203],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32])

# import boundaries of municipalities
# the municipalities are shared through:
# https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/ferreira_ferreira/a-br-municipios

muni = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/ferreira_ferreira/a-br-municipios')

# visualize
import geemap
Map = geemap.Map(center=[-15,-60], zoom=4)

Map.addLayer(sec_veget_age)
Map.addLayer(muni)
Map
```

(zoomed for details. Layer 4 is the vegetation age - remapped = 16, and layer 5 is the municipality boundaries)
[image: Vegetation age by municipality]

So, how should I proceed to have the mentioned table? What combination of functions are best suited for the task. I imagine I'd use a pandas dataframe as long as I have the calculations done. Ideas?

### UPDATE

[Bijoy Krishna Gayen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8625829/bijoy-krishna-gayen) helped me on the Telegram group Google Earth Engine Developers. His solution seems to work. However, I'm having problems validating his solution.

Here is the provided solution:

```py
import ee
ee.Initialize()
import pandas as pd

# importing the dataset
sec_veget_age = ee.Image('projects/mapbiomas-workspace/public/collection6/mapbiomas_collection60_secondary_vegetation_age_v1')

# selecting only vegetation age layer
sec_veget_age = sec_veget_age.select('secondary_vegetation_age_2018')

# the dataset is coded as age/landcover. I only want landcover forest, coded as 03, so I remap the values to show the ages as pixel values
sec_veget_age = sec_veget_age.select('secondary_vegetation_age_2018').remap(
    [103,203,303,403,503,603,703,803,903,1003,1103,1203,1303,1403,1503,1603,1703,1803,1903,2003,2103,2203,2303,2403,2503,2603,2703,2803,2903,3003,3103,3203],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32])

# import boundaries of municipalities
# the municipalities are shared through:
# https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/ferreira_ferreira/a-br-municipios

muni = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/ferreira_ferreira/a-br-municipios')

# here is the solution provided to generate the table I want 
def function_1(item):
    areaDict = ee.Dictionary(item)
    classNumber = ee.Number(areaDict.get('class')).format()
    area = ee.Number(areaDict.get('sum')).divide(10000)
    return ee.List([classNumber, area])

def calculateClassArea(feature):
    areaImage = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(sec_veget_age)
    areas = areaImage.reduceRegion(**{
        "reducer": ee.Reducer.sum().group(**{
        "groupField": 1,
        "groupName": 'class',
      }),
      "geometry": feature.geometry(),
      "scale": 30,
      "maxPixels": 1e10
      });
    classAreas = ee.List(areas.get('groups')) 
    classAreaLists = classAreas.map(function_1) 
    result = ee.Dictionary(classAreaLists.flatten())
    #Here I'm using the municipality national coding system (cd_mun) instead of its name
    cod_igbe = feature.get('cd_mun')
    return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(),result.set('cod_igbe', cod_igbe))

def fc_to_dict(fc):
    prop_names = fc.first().propertyNames()
    prop_lists = fc.reduceColumns(
        reducer=ee.Reducer.toList().repeat(prop_names.size()),
        selectors=prop_names).get('list')
    return ee.Dictionary.fromLists(prop_names, prop_lists)

MunicipalityAreas = muni.map(calculateClassArea);
Municipality_dict = fc_to_dict(MunicipalityAreas).getInfo()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Municipality_dict, orient='index')
df = df.transpose()

df.drop(["system:index"],axis=1,inplace=True)

print(df.head(10))

1           10           11           12          13          14  \
0   668.128153    39.370708    62.167676    65.351822   97.344895   91.846264   
1    257.49818   205.906385   235.752406   223.087317  195.276062  148.105016   
2   368.403266   317.509545   501.875958   504.754521  471.713757  285.398352   
3   1273.17219   227.691104   513.793318   197.185024  369.704333  277.592018   
4   459.594322   139.746977   170.814627   114.687841  103.638578  207.780647   
5  1507.178005   588.560727   597.001127   928.222126  656.499671   577.95249   
6    177.30559   141.955984   258.988731   226.427851  324.499145  118.102114   
7  1393.328464  1413.020431  1487.684552  1366.244439   848.10441  555.926358   
8    273.50529   186.977073   245.540931    285.51216  179.802935  111.269203   
9   384.084367   191.033197   262.167766   304.329699  164.874719  133.154728   

           15          16          17           18  ...          30  \
0   72.312378   63.288666   62.542619    37.174876  ...   16.032236   
1  125.865161  236.599078   97.035892    83.732322  ...   69.875215   
2   225.29586   359.21189  211.669852   147.960731  ...  101.293392   
3  588.727747  366.168818  172.269801   224.970483  ...  156.578405   
4  214.437826  229.355428  125.579114    74.287969  ...  122.917244   
5  449.418351  961.117076   655.00907  1090.746295  ...  254.795102   
6   65.912258  124.157495  101.807628    74.990956  ...   90.029919   
7  602.807776  708.178036   638.20859   842.081171  ...  731.261433   
8   85.751424  148.546357  104.319542   144.003576  ...  228.010047   
9  127.763775  198.941231  265.253704    312.07928  ...  100.936267   

           31          32            4            5            6            7  \
0   22.021802    5.888822   725.172863   398.768665   672.745147   267.780091   
1  208.674079     76.6931   157.103678   173.269095    251.36634   266.946597   
2  172.057107   82.254183   835.804789   673.272592   817.067399    739.95752   
3  175.215727   59.345756   585.161917  1081.712087   806.699397   715.012092   
4  141.604006   73.899154   254.122187   416.240542   466.510453   378.647424   
5  342.663284   113.79043  1494.519018   635.178508   814.009553   762.205842   
6   94.302019   54.348323   410.856503   493.498697   474.073229   335.356558   
7  555.967533  287.724981  1403.520384  1321.103545  1513.591725  1169.728577   
8  162.805297   45.065236   505.168964   296.667542   204.595584   191.148084   
9   94.508095   71.524901   314.881235   375.967294   528.508944   345.753459   

            8           9 cod_igbe  
0   169.69725  149.610375  1200013  
1  259.099238  182.456779  1200054  
2  359.012853  331.024175  1200104  
3  362.950464  192.342908  1200138  
4  172.530579  119.265403  1200179  
5  323.606625  395.093949  1200203  
6  216.609073  168.328085  1200252  
7  1107.66686  792.808057  1200302  
8  114.562788  103.571157  1200328  
9   86.499016  122.287451  1200336  

[10 rows x 33 columns]
```

Ok, it works. But I'm trying to validate the numbers and there is where the problem now lies. I downloaded `sec_veget_age` to check locally. Then I clipped the raster to a single municipality - specifically the one having the code 1304237 (nm_mun = called Tonantins). Then I polygonized the raster and calculated the areas of each polygon to have a look.

The problem is: the table processed on GEE python API gives me:

| cod_igbe | 32 | 31 | 30 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1304237 | 0.259981201171875 | 107.440736475399 | 0.087255419921875 | ... |

And the calculated areas (hectares) of each secondary vegetation age for the same municipality made on QGIS is:

| cod_igbe | 32 | 31 | 30 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1304237 | 444.019 | 414.633 | 112.545 | ... |

As you can see, big differences, and I can't find out why...

Ideas?

Comment: For future reference, instead of having to type out those lists, you could use `list(range(103,3303,100))` (100 is the incremental step) and `list(range(1,33))` (omitting the increment defaults to 1).

Comment: The most likely workflow is to use [reduceRegions()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_reduce_regions) with a [count reducer](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-reducer-count). However, I gave it a quick go and your `muni` feature collection is much too complex (the reduce regions threw a `ee.ee_exception.EEException: Collection.geometry: Geometry has too many edges (15692549 > 2000000)` error). You will need to either simplify it or concentrate on a more focused area of interest.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Matt, In fact the area of interest is the entire Brazil. Regarding to simplify the municipalty borders, I don't think it's an option, since it'll imply on incorrectly account secondary forests among different municipalities. I already have an option and will post it here as a partial answer